# restricted data type attribute violation - ODBC with Access Database

Tags: c++, ms-access, mfc, odbc

I'm trying to add data into my Access database using MFC.
I've two tables and after I add one record to the first table, I retrive the id and update the second table. Everything works fine for the first pass. But for the second record Table 1 rs.Update() throws an exception - restricted data type attribute violation. I'm using the same data for both records. The ID for Table 1 is auto generated.

```
function AddData(){

rs.Open(CRecordset::snapshot, _T("SELECT * FROM Table1"));

for ( each of the objects ) 
{
    db.BeginTrans();
    rs.AddNew();  // Parent table

    m_xx = xx; 
    .......
    .....

   rs.Update(); 

   db.CommitTrans();

   id = GetParentId();  // Get Id of added record

   // Update the second table with id.
   UpdateSecondTable ( id ) ; 

 }
 rs.close(); 

}


int GetParentId(){

 rs.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, _T("SELECT @@Identity FROM Table1"));
 int id = rs.GetFieldValue(); 
 return id; 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`@@identity` doesn't work that well in Access. You have to use the exact same connection to retrieve the inserted ID.

The quick hack to resolve this looks like this:`select max(ID) from table1`

However, this is **not safe** in a multi-user environment.

Comment: *"You have to use the exact same connection to retrieve the inserted ID."* - That is true for most database managers, not just Access.